# can't generate mongoid config file with rails generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

```
shaunstanislaus@Master ~/workspace/mongodb_rails_project/sodibee (master) $ rails g mongoid:config
Could not find generator 'mongoid:config'. Maybe you meant 'migration' or 'controller' or 'generator'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options
```

Comment: i ran bundle install, it is installed and it is inside my gem file.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I resolved it.

Firstly, my `mongoid` is outdated and was using `1.0.6`, the latest current version is `4.0.1`.

Specify in your gems `mongoid`, `4.0.1`

It thus would require you to also include `gem 'moped', '2.0.2'`.

I am assuming you have `bson` and `bson_ext` too.

Then do:

```
spring stop
spring restart
```

Lastly, try:

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

You should see the new file:

```
create  config/mongoid.yml
```

Comment: You don't need to specify moped or bson. These are automatically added when you add mongoid to your Gemfile. It's strange how you installed such an older version of mongoid, since by default `gem "mongoid"` will install 4.x

Comment: @GautamRege gem "mongoid" installs 1.0.6 for recent rails

Comment: spring stop and restart did it for me

Comment: Yep, something about spring was hanging a few different rails commands. I would hit Control+C to stop the command and in the traceback I could see that it was hanging when trying to run Spring.

Answer (score 0):

The older version get's installed when you don't mention a specific mongoid version and the mentioned rails version does not support the latest mongoid version. In this case, the older mongoid version get's installed.

So if this happens with anyone, check the compatibility chart published by mongoid

https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-installation/